# Javascript inheritance design issue

Tags: javascript, inheritance

The following snippet shows how I created my inheritance.  I got inspired by [this](http://www.kevlindev.com/tutorials/javascript/inheritance/inheritance10.htm) article.

```
function Base() {
    this.init();
}

Base.prototype.init = function () {
};

Derived1.prototype = new Base();
Derived1.prototype.constructor = Derived1;
Derived1.superclass = Base.prototype;

function Derived1() {    
}

Derived1.prototype.init = function() {
    Derived1.superclass.init.call(this);
};

Derived2.prototype = new Derived1();
Derived2.prototype.constructor = Derived2;
Derived2.superclass = Derived1.prototype;

function Derived2() {
    Derived2.superclass.init.call(this);
}
```

When this js file is loaded by the browser all the contructors will be called.

```
Derived2.prototype = new Derived1();
```

This can lead to some unexpected behaviour.

Is there any way to stop this behaviour ?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the unexpected behavior?

Comment: For example if you're doing some DOM manipulation in the contructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imo this is a bad inheritance pattern. What if the parent constructor function expects parameters to be passed?

The prototype of the child class should inherit from the prototype of the parent class, not an instance of it. Several libraries implement this way:

```
function inherit(Child, Parent) {
    var F = function(){};
    F.prototype = Parent.prototype;
    Child.prototype = new F();
    Child.prototype.constructor = Child;
}
```

Used as:

```
inherit(Derived1, Base);
```

Then in the child's constructor function, you have to call the parents constructor function:

```
function Child() {
    Parent.call(this);
}
```

Of course you can also add a `superclass` property if you wanted to.